# How to Change bullet colors in wordpress, Only the bullet colors not the text?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am looking for the CSS to change the bullet color in wordpress. Like

- example 1
- exapmle 2

**Note**: I need only to change the bullet colors not the text. Please give me the correct CSS.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: where are examples? @Abdullah Prem

Answer (score 6):

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li:before {
  content: "•";
  color: green;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Example 1</li>
  <li>Example 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, for all your li elements

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.listStyle {
    color: red;
} 
.listStyle span {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="listStyle">
    <li><span>Example1</span></li>
    <li><span>Example2</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For whole wordpress i need to apply not for only one page.